# DotNet: Is it possibly cast dynamic to interface type

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, dllimport, system.reflection

I have an external DLL that contains some business logic.
I would like to perform something like this:

1. Load the DLL in runtime
2. Filter available types by some criteria.
3. Create target type instance
   i.e. dynamic c = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
4. Cast previously created instance to some interface to pass it into handler method

so external dll will contains something like that:

```
namespace External.Handler.Namespace
{
    using System;

    public interface IHandler {
        int Process(string arg);
        int ProcessV2(string arg);
    }

    public class HandlerImpl : IHandler
    {
        public int Process(string arg)
        {
            // ... implementation
            return 0;
        }

        public int ProcessV2(string arg)
        {
            // ... implementation
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

and at target service I would like to load it and try to cast to internal interface

```
namespace My.Target.Namespace
{
    using System;
    using System.Reflection;

    public interface IInternalHandler {
        int Process(string arg)
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var DLL = Assembly.LoadFile(@"path\to\dll");

            foreach(Type type in DLL.GetExportedTypes())
            {
                 dynamic c = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                 try 
                 {
                     // I would like to know: how perform it?
                     var typedInstance = (IInternalInterface) c;
                     Handle(typedInstance);
                 }
                 catch {}
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void Handle(IInternalHandler handler, string arg) {
            int result = handler.Process(arg);
            Console.log(result);
        }
    }
}
```

**To summarize**: Is it possible to convert `dynamic` to **A PARTIALLY** match interface?

Comment: Have you tried: `IInternalInterface c = Activator.CreateInstance(type);`

Comment: @PoulBak yes, and I get the exception `Unable to cast object of type 'ExternalHandlerNamespace.HandlerImpl' to type 'MyTargetNamespace.IInternalHandler'.`

Answer (score 2):

Your `HandlerImpl` class doesn't implement `IInternalHandler`, so you can't cast it to that interface.

You would need to wrap the `dynamic` instance in a class which *does* implement that interface. For example:

```
internal class InternalHandlerWrapper : IInternalHandler
{
    private readonly object _handler;
    
    public InternalHandlerWrapper(object handler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
    }
    
    public int Process(string arg)
    {
        dynamic handler = _handler;
        handler.Process(arg);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach(Type type in DLL.GetExportedTypes())
{
    if (type.IsAbstract || type.IsInterface) continue;
    
    try 
    {
        object c = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        var typedInstance = new InternalHandlerWrapper(c);
        Handle(typedInstance);
    }
    catch {}
}
```

**NB:** The `GetExportedTypes` will also return the `IHandler` interface itself. If you pass that type to `Activator.CreateInstance`, you will get an exception. You need to filter out abstract and interface types from your loop.